# Keep width of div fixed but match height of video element on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to put an image on the side of a video and keep heights of both elements the same. I want to use divs instead of a table but I can't figure out how to do it. The scale on the right side has a fixed width.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <video autoplay loop>
                    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg">
                </video>
            </td>
            <td id="scale"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
video {
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
    display:block;
}

#scale {
    width:16px;
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/vroHDK8.png");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cronwall/Lb6Gd/)

Comment: so you just want to know how to do this same thing but using `div`s? cos it looks like it works currently

Comment: Height is already done i think

Comment: It is my understanding that tables should not be used for layout primarily but for data presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replicate this same effect by using `padding` on the right and an `absolute` positioned `div`

HTML

```
<div id="video">
    <video autoplay loop>
                <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" />
    </video>
    <div id="scale"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
video {
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
    display:block;
}
#video{
    position:relative;
    padding-right:16px;
    display:inline-block; /* if you would like this to remain a block element you could impose the same max-width (+ 16px) as you're doing on the video element */
}
#scale {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:16px;
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/vroHDK8.png");
    background-size: contain;
}
```

see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6Gd/6/